# Creating a ruby function for filtering prime numbers

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration

In the example below, what does `(2..n - 1).all?` mean exactly?

```
def prime?(n)
  if n >=2
    (2..n - 1).all? do |x|
      n % x != 0
    end
  else
    false
  end
end
```

I know that it checks to see if the number passes as `true` but I'd like to get a better understanding.

Comment: Also as an aside [`Prime::prime?`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime-3F) method might be of interest. The source code is written in pure ruby so you can see how the core team went about this.

Comment: Which part in particular is confusing? all? You can look up, ... is a range.

Answer (score 2):

if n = 10

then for every value x between 2 and 9(which is n-1)

n % x must not equal zero

#### more

`(2..n-1)` is a [range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html)

`all?` is a method defined in [Enumerable](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all%3F) which is available to ranges

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to look up how blocks work in Ruby. It's something that threw me when I started out. You are actually passing code(the block) into an iterator to be acted on via a call to yield() within the iterator code. Blocks can take 2 basic forms:

```
(2..n - 1).all? do |x|
  n % x != 0
end
```

is equivalent to

```
(2..n - 1).all? { |x| n % x != 0 }
```

which might be easier to digest at first. In this case the block is:

```
{ |x| n % x != 0 }
```

We can make the range explicit by adding parentheses:

```
(2..(n - 1)).all? { |x| n % x != 0 }
```

The ability to send in code via a block makes it handy when writing iterators. range#all? is such an iterator(I believe). And you can send any code you like as the test you wish everything to pass(since we are talking about all? - if we were talking about any? it would just have to pass once).

|x| is how a parameter gets sent into the block from the iterator code via the yield() call. In this case let's say the current value of the range is represented by i. Then the sent in block would be invoked by a yield(i) call in the iterator. If you examine the code you should see it. So you could put any code you want in the block:

```
(2..(n - 1)).all? { |x| (n + x) < 100 }
```

which should return true as long as n doesn't get too big.

I'll stop there.